# Why won't the DELETE and PUT methods work on my website?

Tags: javascript, mysql, rest, http, server

Im building a basic website which works as task management app. It has 1 endpoint for each HTTP method. The methods im using are: GET, POST, PUT and DELETE. They have to be linked to add, edit, and delete tasks, set due dates and reminders, and organize tasks into categories or projects. But the problem is that my delete and edit buttons are not working. Im going to provide the HTML, and, Client and Server side JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Task.me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="logo.png" alt="Task.me Logo" id="logo">
      <h1>Task.me</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <form id="add-task-form">
        <h2>Add Task</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="new-task">Task:</label>
          <input type="text" id="new-task">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="due-date">Due Date:</label>
          <input type="date" id="due-date">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="category">Category:</label>
          <select id="category">
            <option value="">--Select a category--</option>
            <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
            <option value="Work">Work</option>
            <option value="School">School</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button>Add</button>
      </form>
      <section id="tasks-section">
        <h2>Tasks</h2>
        <ul id="task-list">
          <!-- List of tasks will go here -->
        </ul>
      </section>
    </main>

    <!-- Template for displaying tasks -->
    <template id="task-template">
      <li class="task-item">
        <form class="edit-task-form" hidden>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Task:</label>
            <input type="text" class="edit-task-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Due Date:</label>
            <input type="date" class="edit-due-date">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category:</label>
            <select class="edit-category">
              <option value="">--Select a category--</option>
              <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
              <option value="Work">Work</option>
              <option value="School">School</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <button>Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="cancel-button">Cancel</button>
        </form>
        <div class="view-task">
          <span class="task-name"></span>
          <span class="due-date"></span>
          <span class="category"></span>
          <button class="edit-button">Edit</button>
          <button class="delete-button">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </template>

    <!-- Your HTML code goes here -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

JS CLIENT SIDE

```
// CLIENT SIDE

// Function for retrieving tasks from the web service
async function getTasks() {
    const response = await fetch("/tasks");
    const tasks = await response.json();
    return tasks;
}

// Function for adding a new task using the web service
async function addTask(name, dueDate, category) {
    const response = await fetch("/tasks", {
        method:"POST",
        headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({name,dueDate,category})
    });
    const newTask = await response.json();
    return newTask
}

// Function for updating an existing task using the web service
async function updateTask(id, name, dueDate, category) {
    const response = await fetch(`/tasks/${id}`,{
        method:"PUT",
        headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({name,dueDate,category})
    });
    const updatedTask = await response.json();
    return updatedTask
}

// Function for deleting an existing task using the web service
async function deleteTask(id) {
    const response = await fetch(`/tasks/${id}`,{
        method:"DELETE"
    });
    return response.ok
}

// Function for displaying tasks on the HTML page
async function displayTasks() {
    const tasks = await getTasks();
    console.log("Tasks:", tasks); // added console.log statement
    const taskListElement = document.querySelector("#task-list");
    const taskTemplate = document.querySelector("#task-template");
    taskListElement.innerHTML = "";
    for (const task of tasks) {
        const taskElement = taskTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
        taskElement.querySelector(".task-name").textContent = task.name;
        taskElement.querySelector(".due-date").textContent = task.dueDate;
        taskElement.querySelector(".category").textContent = task.category;
        taskElement.querySelector(".edit-button").dataset.taskId = task.id;
        taskElement.querySelector(".delete-button").dataset.taskId = task.id;
        taskListElement.appendChild(taskElement);
    }
}


// Function for handling the submit event of the add-task form
function handleAddTaskFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    const name = form.elements["new-task"].value;
    const dueDate = form.elements["due-date"].value;
    const category = form.elements["category"].value;
    addTask(name, dueDate, category)
        .then(() => displayTasks())
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

// Function for handling the click event of the edit buttons
function handleEditButtonClick(event) {
    console.log("Edit button clicked"); // added console.log statement
    const taskId = parseInt(event.currentTarget.dataset.taskId);
    console.log("Task ID:", taskId); // added console.log statement
    const taskElement = event.currentTarget.closest(".task-item");
    console.log("Task element:", taskElement); // added console.log statement
    if (taskElement) {
        const viewTaskElement = taskElement.querySelector(".view-task");
        const editTaskForm = taskElement.querySelector(".edit-task-form");
        viewTaskElement.hidden = true;
        editTaskForm.hidden = false;
        
        // added code to populate edit-task form with current values
        editTaskForm.elements["edit-task-name"].value = viewTaskElement.querySelector(".task-name").textContent;
        editTaskForm.elements["edit-due-date"].value = viewTaskElement.querySelector(".due-date").textContent;
        editTaskForm.elements["edit-category"].value = viewTaskElement.querySelector(".category").textContent;
    }
}



// Function for handling the submit event of the edit-task forms
function handleEditTaskFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    const taskId = parseInt(form.closest(".task-item").querySelector(".edit-button").dataset.taskId);
    const name = form.elements["edit-task-name"].value;
    const dueDate = form.elements["edit-due-date"].value;
    const category = form.elements["edit-category"].value;
    updateTask(taskId, name, dueDate, category)
        .then(() => displayTasks())
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

// Function for handling the click event of the cancel buttons
function handleCancelButtonClick(event) {
    const taskId = parseInt(event.currentTarget.closest(".task-item").querySelector(".edit-button").dataset.taskId);
    const taskElement = event.currentTarget.closest(".task-item");
    const viewTaskElement = taskElement.querySelector(".view-task");
    const editTaskForm = taskElement.querySelector(".edit-task-form");
    viewTaskElement.hidden = false;
    editTaskForm.hidden = true;
}

// Function for handling the click event of the delete buttons
function handleDeleteButtonClick(event) {
    const taskId = parseInt(event.currentTarget.dataset.taskId);
    deleteTask(taskId)
        .then(() => displayTasks())
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

// Add event listeners when the page loads
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    // Display tasks when the page loads
    displayTasks();

    // Add event listener for the submit event of the add-task form
    const addTaskForm = document.querySelector("#add-task-form");
    addTaskForm.addEventListener("submit", handleAddTaskFormSubmit);

    // Add event listeners for the click event of the edit, delete, and cancel buttons
    // and the submit event of the edit-task forms
    // using event delegation
    const taskListElement = document.querySelector("#task-list");
    taskListElement.addEventListener("click", event => {
        if (event.target.matches(".edit-button")) {
            handleEditButtonClick(event);
        } else if (event.target.matches(".delete-button")) {
            handleDeleteButtonClick(event);
        } else if (event.target.matches(".cancel-button")) {
            handleCancelButtonClick(event);
        }
    });
    taskListElement.addEventListener("submit", event => {
        if (event.target.matches(".edit-task-form")) {
            handleEditTaskFormSubmit(event);
        }
    });
});
```

SERVER SIDE

```
// server/index.js
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql"); // added require statement for mysql module

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/home.html");
});

// Create a connection to the MySQL database
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "tasks_db"
});

// Connect to the MySQL database
connection.connect();

// GET endpoint for retrieving all tasks
app.get("/tasks", (req, res) => {
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM tasks", (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    } else {
      res.json(results);
    }
  });
});

// POST endpoint for adding a new task
app.post("/tasks", (req, res) => {
  const newTask = {
    name: req.body.name,
    dueDate: req.body.dueDate,
    category: req.body.category
  };
  connection.query("INSERT INTO tasks SET ?", newTask, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    } else {
      newTask.id = results.insertId;
      res.json(newTask);
    }
  });
});

// PUT endpoint for updating an existing task
app.put("/tasks/:id", (req, res) => {
  const taskId = parseInt(req.params.id);
  const updatedTask = {
    name: req.body.name,
    dueDate: req.body.dueDate,
    category: req.body.category
  };
  connection.query("UPDATE tasks SET ? WHERE id = ?", [updatedTask, taskId], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    } else if (results.affectedRows === 0) {
      res.status(404).send("Task not found");
    } else {
      updatedTask.id = taskId;
      res.json(updatedTask);
    }
  });
});

// DELETE endpoint for deleting an existing task
app.delete("/tasks/:id", (req, res) => {
  const taskId = parseInt(req.params.id);
  connection.query("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = ?", taskId, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    } else if (results.affectedRows === 0) {
      res.status(404).send("Task not found");
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(204);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

The errors im facing when the DELETE AND EDIT TASK buttons are clicked are (The following error are from the browser's developer tools):

```
EDIT BUTTON CLICKED: 
Task ID:NaN
Task element: -null

DELETE BUTTON CLICKED:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
RESPONSE: 
{
    "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
    "errno": 1054,
    "sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause'",
    "sqlState": "42S22",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id = NaN"
}
```

Also, im using a connection to MYSQL for a database. [DATABASE SETUP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR9xH.png)

Can't seem to grasp where the issue is. Id really appreciate your help. Please.

Comment: There's quite a lot of code there. Please provide a _minimal_ reproducible example - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Also note that Java is not the same as JavaScript - I've fixed the tags.

Comment: Seems, that the `taskId` you receive in your path on the server side is not a valid number and cannot be parsed to an int. Quite hard to say, where that comes from with that amount of code. Bit try using the network inspector of your browser to check what request is really sent. Also add breakpoints in your after your `cloneNode` call to check what the `task.id` really is. And finally you can add a breakpoint in your eventhandler to see, what taskid is actually received from the dataset

Comment: You can also set a breakpoint on the server side and inspect the value of `req.params.id`

Answer (score -1):

Update the task for handleEditButtonClick function in js file.

```
const taskId = parseInt(event.currentTarget.dataset.taskId);
```

Update the task for handleDeleteButtonClick function in js file.

```
const taskId = parseInt(event.currentTarget.dataset.taskId);
```

Also, make sure you have a primary key.

Comment: How would that help? `parseInt` is executed on the server side and leads to `NaN` which means, somewhere an invalid taskid is set.